Run MSTest programmatically
I have an existing library containing unit tests. I want to transform that library into a service that periodically runs the unit tests and emit metrics. I solved the bits to create a service and to emit metrics, but the part I am not able to tackle is how to run the unit tests programmatically, eg, from a stateless service, not from visual studio. I would like to avoid relying on a Process or to have to migrate to NUnit
I couldn't find a documented way to do that truthfully, so I am pretty stuck. It seems this framework is only designed for CLI/VS usage if I trust https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-mstest-runner-intro. The NUnit approach seemed a bit more promising, but that has a migration cost, especially since we rely on runsettings files.

Is there a reason why you didn't pick an existing continuous integration tool? Why not run the tests by invoking dotnet test which can be done by starting a new process? To my knowledge, MS Test does not expose a test runner than you can new-up in C#.

I'm sorry, but you are kind of fighting the framework, here.

@GregBurghardt because I am not building continuous integration in the sense of 'run the tests when a new commit arrives and check the overall status'. I want to run tests every x seconds and emit the outcome in a metric I can alarm on. And finally, I want the test to run with different parameters depending on the environment they run in, so a service with application parameters make sense.

Ok. So why not invoke dotnet test from the service? I know you don't want to deal with processes, but you have no alternative with MS Test.

essentially because our metrics library requires the runtime context of the service, which I believe I won't get through a process. In the end, I migrated to Nunit and it worked that way, not sure if I could have made it simpler staying with MSTest
